# DIJIT TabContainer display problems in IE7

Tags: dojo, tabcontainer

I am having an issue with a tabcontainer displaying tabs vertically, rather than horizontally in IE7.  Firefox 3.5 is fine.

My setup is as follows:
Tab container contains 5 tabs.
Tab container has CSS defined by a custom CSS file
Each tab can contain a new tab container
This 'inner' tab container uses the default tundra css styling.

The 'inner' tab containers works fine, and displays the tabs horizontally but the 'outer' tab container (with the custom css) doesn't.  I thought solving this problem would be straight forward, as I'd just be able to copy the relevant styling from the tundra style sheets.  Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.
I've checked the display values of the computed css for all of the inner and outer tabs  and they match up so I'm now at a bit of a loss.......

Has anyone had this sort of issue before?

Oh, and there is another, slightly confusing issue............if I don't apply     "display: inline-block;" to  .dijitTab I get the same problem in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing your custom CSS but there is a _rectifyRtlTabList() method on TabController that fixes a similar problem